# HTML Email : Making triangle to the bottom of td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make a triangle as described in the image.

[image: Image with triangle to the bottom]

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 0px;">
                        <span style="background: #EE163A !important; width: 100px; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; color: #FFFFFF;padding: 10px 70px; "> DAY 1</span>
                    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

PS : As I am making HTML Emailer , so can't use `position` , `div` , `after:` , `before`. I have to use `table` and **inline-css** , only.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: I have tried using triangle image. but it didn't work.

Comment: Look into this for starters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work ... And then apply.

Comment: you have to make another `td` as `<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">` below it with the *triangle image* of same color it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 0px;">
            <span style="background: #EE163A !important; width: 100px; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; color: #FFFFFF;padding: 10px 70px; "> DAY 1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="arrow" style="margin-left:-100px; width: 0; height: 0; border-top: solid 5px #EE163A; border-left: solid 5px transparent; border-right: solid 5px transparent; display: block; margin-top: 37px;"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: as I have mentioned , I can't use `position`, `after: `

Comment: Ok see the updated snippet.